# Nano Ledger and baking

Tags: baking, ledger

I’m looking to delegate my Tezos for some baking. Considering hardware options, can I use a Nano Ledger X or only a Nano Ledger S.

Answer (score 2):

Ledger has indicated that applications for the Ledger Nano S will also work on the Ledger Nano X, although by default they will not take advantage of the device's difference from the Nano S such as the larger screen and bluetooth capabilities.

We (Obsidian Systems) are awaiting delivery of a few Ledger Nano X devices so we can confirm that and begin development specific to the device :)

Answer (score 1):

You can delegate with the Ledger. I know of three (soon four) good guides.

- Using a [command line approach](https://github.com/obsidiansystems/ledger-app-tezos) (the `tezos-client`). This requires that you run a node. Yet, if you do so, then why not to bake yourself? The link contains information on baking with the Ledger. There is now an easy to use GUI available too, with Kiln (see [here](https://medium.com/@obsidian.systems/bake-with-kiln-a-call-for-beta-testers-d0b65a44e205) or [here](https://gitlab.com/obsidian.systems/tezos-bake-monitor)).
- Using [Tezbox](https://medium.com/cryptium/how-to-store-your-tezos-xtz-in-your-ledger-nano-s-and-delegate-with-tezbox-wallet-8fb4ac2d3355).
- Using [Magnum Wallet](https://medium.com/cryptium/how-to-store-your-tezos-xtz-in-your-ledger-nano-s-and-delegate-with-magnum-wallet-3871dc4bd3b7).
- (soon) Using [Bakechain](https://bakechain.github.io/#home)