# Using Ledger Nano S to bake/endorse. Guide?

Tags: baking, node, ledger

Yesterday, I was able to spin up a node from source using the command line interface on my MacBook Pro. As I am waiting for the node to sync, I am looking for documentation so I can run my baker/endorser with my Ledger Nano S. Currently, I am baking with BakeChain client. I don’t want lose my rights that have been assigned while I was using BakeChain. Any leads?

Comment: Related: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/830/nano-ledger-x-and-baking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 0.5.0 of Kiln allows you to bake from the Ledger Nano S using a GUI (rather than command line approach, as the one in the other answer). See [here](https://medium.com/@obsidian.systems/bake-with-kiln-a-call-for-beta-testers-d0b65a44e205) or [here](https://gitlab.com/obsidian.systems/tezos-bake-monitor).

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://github.com/obsidiansystems/ledger-app-tezos) you can find the guide from the developers of the Ledger Nano baking app (Obsidian System).

However, I would recommend to download the app from Ledger Live and not compile it yourself, and then follow the guide from after the compiling instructions.

Comment: My baking app on my ledger was registered using BakeChain. I have node up running. I am having difficulty connecting my ledger to the node and registering my baker with the node...I am not sure this make sense